# How to count 5 minutes from now?

Tags: rust

I need to count 5 minutes from now in Rust. I thought I could use [`time::now()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/time/struct.Tm.html) but it's deprecated. What can I use and how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mouse over the "deprecated" note in the documentation, you'll see that it points you to [the `rust-lang/time` repository](https://github.com/rust-lang/time/).  Basically, it got moved out of the standard library into its own package.

Provided you add a dependency on the `time` crate as specified in the documentation, this works:

```
extern crate time;

use std::time::duration::Duration;

fn main() {
    let now = time::get_time();
    println!("now:   {}", now);
    let later = now + Duration::minutes(5);
    println!("later: {}", later);
}
```

Comment: so how do I count 5 minutes from now?

Comment: The same way you would with `std::time`: it's *the same library*, it's just been moved out from the standard distribution.

Comment: How would I do that with std::time?