# Format std::time output

Tags: time, rust

I want to display the current time in a certain format.

I am trying to avoid the [time crate](https://crates.io/crates/time) since it's flagged as deprecated on its [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/rust-lang-deprecated/time).

I want to use this exact format `time::now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d][%H:%M:%S").unwrap()` using `std::time`, but it doesn't seems to have a `strftime`.

Comment: For anyone seeing this nowadays, the `time` crate may be revived soon. I've asked on GitHub to take it over, and already have support from two contributors.

Comment: The `time` crate is revived and is being considered for inclusion in `std`.

Comment: Having the `time` crate in `std` would be a Godsend to shops that have to go through a review process for each third party dependency.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are (currently) two `now` methods: [`Instant::now`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Instant.html#method.now) and [`SystemTime::now`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html#method.now).

`Instant` says:

> A measurement of a monotonically increasing clock. Opaque and useful only with `Duration`.

`SystemTime` says:

> A measurement of the system clock, useful for talking to external entities like the file system or other processes.

Neither of these is truly appropriate for showing to a human. Time is **hard**, and *formatting* time is additional complexity. It's really a good thing that it's not part of the standard library, otherwise it would have a fixed API that couldn't be improved.

As mentioned elsewhere, I'd recommend using [chrono](https://github.com/lifthrasiir/rust-chrono), the *heir apparent* to the `time` crate.

Comment: strftime has been part of the C standard library for 50 years. It has been improved without changing the API (adding format specifiers if nothing else). Most languages have it implemented natively or at least a wrapper to the clib. I'm fairly new to rust, but it seems like not having date formatting in the stdlib makes the language feel a little underbaked.

Answer (score 42):

You can use the crate [`chrono`](https://crates.io/crates/chrono) to achieve the same result:

```
extern crate chrono;

use chrono::Local;

fn main() {
    let date = Local::now();
    println!("{}", date.format("%Y-%m-%d][%H:%M:%S"));
}
```

**Edit:**

The time crate is not deprecated: it is unmaintained.

Besides, it is not possible to format a time using only the standard library.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the result of `std::time::now()` to a Chrono compatible type? OP asked for how to format something from `std::time`, not how to print the current time (for better or worse).

Comment: Plus the crate chrono is just a wrapper for the crate time.

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne The chrono crate has been updated 12 days ago. I don't believe it is deprecated.

Comment: @antoyo : on the repo [https://github.com/rust-lang-deprecated/time](rust-lang-depreciated), the last update was 5 month ago. Plus it has been flagged as depreciated because all of the code has been migrated to the rust std lib

Comment: @antoyo plus I can reffer you to this [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221193/time-in-rust-time-crate-is-deprecated). I just don't want to add more dependencies to my project

Comment: Do you want to continue this discussion on the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust)?

Answer (score 8):

Since the [time](https://crates.io/crates/time) crate seems to be revived, you no longer need to avoid using it. That being said, you can continue using `std::time` (which is in fact kind of what the `time` crate does) in addition to `strftime`-like formatting capabilities of the `time` crate.

```
use time::OffsetDateTime;
use std::time::SystemTime;

const DATE_FORMAT_STR: &'static str = "%Y-%m-%d][%H:%M:%S";

fn main() {
    let dt: OffsetDateTime = SystemTime::now().into();
    let dt2 = OffsetDateTime::now_utc();  // Also uses std::time (v0.2.26)

    println!("{}", dt.format(DATE_FORMAT_STR));
    println!("{}", dt2.format(DATE_FORMAT_STR));
}
```

[Play](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=use%20time%3A%3AOffsetDateTime%3B%0D%0Ause%20std%3A%3Atime%3A%3ASystemTime%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20DATE_FORMAT_STR%3A%20%26%27static%20str%20%3D%20%22%25Y-%25m-%25d%5D%5B%25H%3A%25M%3A%25S%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20dt%3A%20OffsetDateTime%20%3D%20SystemTime%3A%3Anow().into()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Using%20std%3A%3Atime%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20dt2%20%3D%20OffsetDateTime%3A%3Anow_utc()%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Technically%20also%20uses%20std%3A%3Atime%20(v0.2.26)%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20dt.format(DATE_FORMAT_STR))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20dt2.format(DATE_FORMAT_STR))%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Note (quoting doc page):

> Time’s formatting behavior is based on strftime in C, though it is explicitly **not** compatible. Specifiers may be missing, added, or have different behavior than in C.

So be sure to check [this](https://docs.rs/time/*/time/#formatting) (i.e. the table) to make sure you are using the right specifiers.

Comment: I'm trying it in Rust Playground right now, it doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix that? Otherwise the solution seems very interesting! (I'm using the very same playground link you provided.)

Comment: Rust playground doesn't work for me, either -- and I can't get it working locally. I have `time = { version = "0.3.11", features = ["formatting"] }`

Comment: Huh, it works with version = 0.2.26. So when was this deprecated and what is the new API call?

Comment: Got it working on 0.3.11! [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c1b95fd188437218cdd1d97f0a771007)