# How to format SystemTime to string?

Tags: time, rust

It seems there is no way I can turn `SystemTime` into a string. I have to use `SystemTime` because I need the value returned from `std::fs::Metadata::created()`.

Comment: See also [Format std::time output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38957718/155423)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should use Chrono for its formatting support. Since Chrono v0.4.0 this is much easier, as it now implements direct conversions from `std::time::SystemTime`:

```
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::offset::Utc;
use chrono::DateTime;
use std::time::SystemTime;

let system_time = SystemTime::now();
let datetime: DateTime<Utc> = system_time.into();
println!("{}", datetime.format("%d/%m/%Y %T"));
```

If you wanted the time in local timezone instead of UTC, use [`Local`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/offset/struct.Local.html) instead of `Utc`.

For the full list of formatting specifiers see the [Chrono documentation](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/format/strftime/index.html).

Comment: Is this still the best way in 2021? I really wish Rust stdlib supports SystemTime display.

Comment: Yeah, this is annoying because the Chrono crate has a security advisory that doesn't seem to be going away anytime soon.

Answer (score 5):

The [`time`](https://crates.io/crates/time) crate is now a viable alternative to `chrono`. See the [`format()` method](https://docs.rs/time/*/time/struct.OffsetDateTime.html#method.format) for details on returning a `String` from an `OffsetDateTime`. Also make sure to check the [`strftime` specifiers table](https://docs.rs/time/*/time/index.html#formatting) when making your formatting string.

```
use time::OffsetDateTime;
use std::time::SystemTime;

fn systemtime_strftime<T>(dt: T, format: &str) -> String
   where T: Into<OffsetDateTime>
{
    dt.into().format(format)
}

fn main() {
    let st = SystemTime::now();
    println!("{}", systemtime_strftime(st, "%d/%m/%Y %T"));
}
```

[Play](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=use%20time%3A%3AOffsetDateTime%3B%0D%0Ause%20std%3A%3Atime%3A%3ASystemTime%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afn%20systemtime_strftime%3CT%3E(dt%3A%20T%2C%20format%3A%20%26str)%20-%3E%20String%0D%0A%20%20%20where%20T%3A%20Into%3COffsetDateTime%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dt.into().format(format)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20st%20%3D%20SystemTime%3A%3Anow()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20systemtime_strftime(st%2C%20%22%25d%2F%25m%2F%25Y%20%25T%22))%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: What you linked in *Play* does *`not compile \`playground\` (bin "playground") due to 3 previous errors`*.

Comment: The [API](https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/struct.OffsetDateTime.html) appears to have been changed. `format()` is now _Available on crate feature formatting only._ and its parameter now requires the `Formattable` trait.

Comment: You might want to use: `let t: OffsetDateTime = SystemTime::now().into();` `println!("{:0>4}-{:0>2}-{:0>2} {:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}", t.year(), t.month() as u8, t.day(), t.hour(), t.minute(), t.second());`